# Create an Outlook 2003 toolbar using VBA

Tags: vba, toolbar, outlook-2003

In Excel 2003 I can access the collection `Application.CommandBars` to create custom toolbars using VBA. Is there an equivalent in Outlook 2003?

I am trying to change the labels on buttons of a customer toolbar. In the future I'd like to create the toolbar from scratch.

Cheers,
Dave

--Trindaz on Fedang #Outlook-vbas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up solving this one myself. Here's the code if you're interested:

```
Dim expExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Dim cmbCommandBar As CommandBar
Dim ctlBarControl As CommandBarControl
For Each expExplorer In Outlook.Explorers
    For Each cmbCommandBar In expExplorer.CommandBars
        If cmbCommandBar.Name = "name-of-toolbar" Then
            For Each ctlBarControl In cmbCommandBar.Controls
                If ctlBarControl.Caption = "caption-i-want-to-change" Then
                    ctlBarControl.Caption = "new-caption-text"
                End If
            Next ctlBarControl
        End If
    Next cmbCommandBar
Next expExplorer
```

Comment: This reply doesn't address your original question about creating a custom toolbar from scratch.

Comment: Creating a toolbar from scratch was something I hoped to do in the future. The problem I as facing was "trying to change the labels on buttons of a customer toolbar", which my solution does. Is English your native language? If it is I'm genuinely interested in what your thought process was leading up to down-voting me.

Comment: No it's not my native language, sorry if I misinterpreted the original question or sounded harsh but I'm looking for a full solution and I feel it should be there in the accepted answer while it's not, thus the downvoting. The title of your question is `Create an Outlook 2003 toolbar using VBA` which can't be more explicit. Feel free to edit your answer.